# Date being stored incorrectly in database

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

When the date is entered in the textbox in the format `DD/MM/YYYY` if the day is earlier than 12 it is stored as `MM/DD/YYYY`. I need it to be stored as typed.

```
protected void InsertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Int32 claim = (Int32)Session["Claim"];
    string claim1 = Convert.ToString(claim);
    Label4.Text = "Claim Number : " + (String)claim1;
    Label4.Visible = true;

    // declare variables to hold info enterend by user
    string expenseType;
    string purpose;
    decimal amount;
    DateTime date;
    Boolean receipts;

    //assign info entered to variables entered above
    expenseType = DropDownList1. Text;
    purpose = PurposeofExpenseTextBox.Text;
    amount = Convert.ToDecimal(AmountSpentTextBox.Text);
    date = Convert.ToDateTime(DatePurchasedTextBox.Text);
    receipts = CheckBox1.Checked;
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;

    // create connection string "conn"
    string mapPath = Server.MapPath(".");
    string ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
       @"Data source= "*****";
    OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);



    try
    {
        //create query to insert values into Expenses table   
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Expenses (ExpenseType, PurposeofExpense, AmountSpent, DatePurchased, strEmpName, Receipts, EmployeeID, ExpNumber) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExpenseType", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DropDownList1.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PurposeofExpense", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = PurposeofExpenseTextBox.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@AmountSpent", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = AmountSpentTextBox.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@DatePurchased", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DatePurchasedTextBox.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@strEmpName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = (String)Session["New"];
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Receipts", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = CheckBox1.Checked;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmployeeID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = (String)Session["Number"];
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ExpNumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = (Int32)Session["Claim"];


        //open connection "conn"
        conn.Open();
        //execute insert query
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I think you'd need to insert it using the right format: `YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS`. Then you'd need to format it when you display it.

Comment: date = DateTime.ParseExact(DatePurchasedTextBox.Text,"DD/MM/YYYY",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);

Comment: you are storing it in `varchar` field and it should also be in the same format as your textfield, not sure how you infer that it is of `MM/dd/yyyy` format ? Also why not declare variables as you did for `DateTime today = DateTime.Today;` ! !

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms714540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Date values must be either delimited according to the ODBC canonical
>   date format or delimited by the datetime delimiter ("#"). Otherwise,
>   Microsoft Access will treat the value as an arithmetic expression and
>   will not raise a warning or error. For example, the date "March 5,
>   1996" must be represented as {d '1996-03-05'} or #03/05/1996#;
>   otherwise, if only 03/05/1993 is submitted, Microsoft Access will
>   evaluate this as 3 divided by 5 divided by 1996. This value rounds up
>   to the integer 0, and since the zero day maps to 1899-12-31, this is
>   the date used. A pipe character (|) cannot be used in a date value,
>   even if enclosed in back quotes.

You need to check the date format before saving. Use some mask.